# Unity3D movement right/left fail

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I'm making an endless runner game, and I have stuck on a problem. I need my charater to move left to right, but it wont do it.
I need it to move smooth from left to right and not in lanes. Since my game will be having random object popping up all over the trail.

I have assigened the left and right key to A and D in Unity.

Is it my code?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Ballmove : MonoBehaviour {

public KeyCode moveL;
public KeyCode moveR;

public float horizVel = -4;
// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = new Vector3(-4, 0, 0);

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(moveL))
    {
        horizVel = -5;
        StartCoroutine(stopSlid());
    }
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(moveR))
    {
        horizVel = 5;
        StartCoroutine(stopSlid());
    }
}
IEnumerator stopSlid()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
    horizVel = -4;
}
}
```

Comment: Did you debug your code? `horizVel` is not assigned to any component in this code so that means you're not moving anything.

Comment: The debugging told me nothing. But i did find my problem, thanks to you!

Comment: it seems you never actually use your horizVel variable, you assign the velocity to be hard left, regardless of everything

Comment: Maybe its just my personal preference, but I would use MovePosition for this instead of setting velocity.

Comment: @Kunak would you submit your solve as an answer? You can accept your own answers. I would hate to leave questions with an "I solved, it. Thanks!" and no actual answer was listed.

Comment: @LeoBartkus Can you give me an example to use MovePosition? I will like to learn that aswell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically I forgot to assign horizVel and I also assigned the velocity to go left. I fixed the problem by doing this:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Ballmove : MonoBehaviour {

public KeyCode moveL;
public KeyCode moveR;

public float horizVel = 0;
// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = new Vector3(-4, GM.vertVol, horizVel);

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(moveL))
    {
        horizVel = -3;
        StartCoroutine(stopSlid());
    }
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(moveR))
    {
        horizVel = 3;
        StartCoroutine(stopSlid());
    }
}
IEnumerator stopSlid()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);
    horizVel = 0;
}

}
```

So this line`GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = new Vector3(-4, GM.vertVol, horizVel);` should be `GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = new Vector3(-4, 0, horizVel);` I have added some more since the fix.

Answer (score 0):

You could use moveposition instead of velocity if you want to have more precise control over the object's position.

```
// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    var horizVel = 0;
    if (Input.GetKey(moveL))
    {
        horizVel += 3;
    }
    if (Input.GetKey(moveR))
    {
        horizVel -= 3;
    }

    GetComponent<Rigidbody>().MovePosition(this.transform.position + new Vector3(-4, GM.vertVol, horizVel) * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

}

Comment: Thank you, I will try that!